# dual for loops to find missing number from the entered sequence

Tags: java, for-loop

Need help to complete this learner with for loops

Program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int id[] = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
            id[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Input Format:
The first input consists of an integer `n` corresponding to the number of IDs.
Next `n` inputs corresponds to the Ids.

Output Format:
Output should display the missing Id.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Besides that you probably have an array out of bounds exception in there, your code looks fine.  What is the actual question?

Comment: hmmmm, how to print a _missing_ id? If you managed to get your program running, I'd like to use it to find 6 missing lotto numbers.

Comment: Hi, Output should be somewhat like this.. Sample Input and Output:
  5 -- >total number of IDs
1
2
3
5
6
Customer id 4 is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you can get the missing in between number according to the sequence you entered.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        int missingTrack = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter number of sequence:");
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int id[] = new int[n];
        int missing[] = new int[10];

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter number %d:",i+1);
            id[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {

            //Stop to check when the loop reach the last number in the sequence.
            if(i==n-1)
            {
                break;
            }
            //Assign the different between the next number to identify the missing number
            num = id[i+1]-id[i];

            //Loop based on the difference we get from "num"
            for(int y = 1;y<num;y++)
            {
                //Evaluate and store the missing number into the array
                missing[missingTrack] = id[i]+y;
                missingTrack = missingTrack+1;
            }

        }   
        System.out.println("Missing input: ");
        for(int i=0; i < missingTrack; i++) {
            System.out.print(missing[i]+" ");
        }

}
```

With the dual For loop to check and keep track of the missing number, hope you can get an idea on how to implement it to your scenario.

PS: Assume the sequence entered is in ascending order. Extra checking or sorting need to be done first if the input is entered not in sequential manner.

Comment: Can you help explain this portion:                                                           
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {

            if(i==n-1)
            {
                break;
            }
            num = id[i+1]-id[i];

            for(int y = 1;y<num;y++)
            {
                missing[missingTrack] = id[i]+y;
                missingTrack = missingTrack+1;
            }

        }   
        System.out.println("Missing input: ");
        for(int i=0; i < missingTrack; i++) {
            System.out.print(missing[i]+" ");
        }

Comment: The first loop will loop through the input sequence and get the gap between the next number and store it in num. Then loop based on the value of num and calculate the missing number then insert it into a integer array called missing. missingTrack will keep track the latest index to be inserted into missing array.

Comment: I have put in some comments to ease your understanding. HTH.

Comment: Thanks Akjun for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

I just write a function that may help you:

```
  public class Enrollment {
    public static void prinMiss(int arr[],int size)
    {
        int y=arr[0];
        //System.out.println(y);
        int y1=arr[size-1];
        //System.out.println(y1);

        int counter=y;
        int flag=0;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==counter)
            {
                //System.out.println(counter);
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==1){
        System.out.println(counter);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Nothing is missing");
    }
public static void main(String ars[])
{
    Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    n=in.nextInt();
    int id[]=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        id[i]=in.nextInt();
    }
    prinMiss(id,n);
}
}
```

In above **prinMiss** function i have assumed that the IDs will always be in sequence and only 1 ID is out of sequence.